# sticky first row of table with the same column width

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

I'm trying to create sticky first row of table (header), but when i do it, the header has different column width.

When the table is loaded it looks like:

```
   |   heada    |   headb    |   headc    |   headd    |
   |  contenta  |  contentb  |  contentc  |  contentd  |
   |  contenta  |  contentb  |  contentc  |  contentd  |
```

When i scroll down it looks like:

```
   | heada | headb | headc | headd |                   |
   |  contenta  |  contentb  |  contentc  |  contentd  |
   |  contenta  |  contentb  |  contentc  |  contentd  |
```

html/php:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($show_firm) >0)
{
  echo '<table class="tableList">';

       // first tr/header

  echo'<tr class="tableListforstickymenu">';        

       foreach($show_columns_firm as $key => $v)
       {
          echo '<td class="tableList-TD-first">'.$v.'</td>';
       }
  echo '</tr>';

      // other tr

  while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($show_firm))
  {                 
      echo'<tr class="tableList">';
      foreach($show_columns_firm as $key => $v)
      {
          echo '<td class="tableList-TD-first">'.$v.'</td>';
      }
      echo '</tr></table>';
  }
 }
```

css:

```
.tableListforstickymenu {
    border: 1px solid #DBF4FF;
    background-color: #B9DBE8;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    text-align: left;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    table-layout: fixed;
    padding: 10px 1px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.stickymenu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 130px;
    z-index: 100;
    border: 0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
   var stickyNavTop = $('.tableListforstickymenu').offset().top;

   var stickyNav = function()
    {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) 
        { 
            $('.tableListforstickymenu').addClass('stickymenu');
        }
        else 
        {
            $('.tableListforstickymenu').removeClass('stickymenu'); 
        }
  };
  stickyNav();
  $(window).scroll(function()
  {
      stickyNav();
  });
 });
```

I don't know how to align the first sticky row (header) with rest of table.
One more thing: table is wider than screen (its about 30 columns and has scrolls).

Comment: You have class tableList or your lower list. Is that right? We can't see the CSS for that class.

Comment: tableList = tableListforstickymenu :)

Comment: Check you have closed all your <td>s with </td> Is one missing at all?

Comment: actually, its wrote in php, so it looks like `echo '<td class="tableList-TD-first">'.$v.'</td>';` etc. There is no way to miss any <td> or </td>

Comment: Have you looked at the dev tools to see why it is styled that way?

Comment: Well yes but i can't see there nothing wrong. It seems i need to add something to jQuery. I need to get width of each column to sticky row but i dont know how.:( I am not good at jquery

Comment: That shouldn't have anything to do with it. As a test put tableListforstickymenu as the class for the second one. See if it temporarily fixes it.

Comment: that will be tricky because others <tr> are from php loop(foreach)

Comment: Can't you change the php? I suspect that your actual output is not as you haven posted here. I would start by checking your dev tools and see where the  CSS style of the incorrect row is coming from. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: yes, i know. And i'll update post and add php. I thought the problem is in jquery.

Comment: there is one more thing. maybe this is because my table is wider than screen? there is about 30 columns but it has to be like that :(
And ofcourse sticky row won't scroll on sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a CSS / HTML issue, I've split your table into two (awkward things happen when you start splitting html tables in this way) - it's better practice to use css only for layout situations like this and not html tables (this split will need to be reflected in your php) then your css should address the width of both tables. Your js should now be adapted to target the top table.

change the class label of your initial table declaration at the top of your php and in the middle of your php change:

```
echo '</tr>';
```

to:

```
echo '</tr></table><table class="tableList"><tr class="tableList">';
```

should do the trick

snippet here:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
 {
   var stickyNavTop = $('.tableListforstickymenu').offset().top;

   var stickyNav = function()
    {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
          scrollLeft= $(window).scrollLeft();

        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) 
        { 
            $('.tableList-top').addClass('stickymenu');
        }
        else 
        {
            $('.tableList-top').removeClass('stickymenu'); 
        }
        
        $('.stickymenu').css({ left: -scrollLeft + 8 }); // the +8 is due to the padding you have on the main table css
        
  };
  stickyNav();
  $(window).scroll(function()
  {
      stickyNav();
  });
 });
```

```css
.tableListforstickymenu {
    border: 1px solid #DBF4FF;
    background-color: #B9DBE8;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    text-align: left;
    table-layout: fixed;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 10px 1px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.stickymenu{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    border: 0;
}

table.tableList-top td, table.tableList td{
  min-width: 5em; /* recommend using em's or px and not % here */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableList-top">
    <tr class="tableListforstickymenu">
        <td class="tableList-TD-first">alpha</td>
        <td class="tableList-TD-first">bravo</td>
        <td class="tableList-TD-first">charlie</td>
        <td class="tableList-TD-first">delta</td>
        <td class="tableList-TD-first">echo</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="tableList">
<tr class="tableList">
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_a</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_b</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_c</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_d</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_e</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tableList">
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_a</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_b</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_c</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_d</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_e</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tableList">
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_a</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_b</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_c</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_d</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_e</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tableList">
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_a</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_b</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_c</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_d</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_e</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tableList">
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_a</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_b</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_c</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_d</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_e</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tableList">
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_a</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_b</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_c</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_d</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_e</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableList">
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_a</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_b</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_c</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_d</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_e</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableList">
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_a</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_b</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_c</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_d</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_e</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableList">
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_a</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_b</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_c</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_d</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_e</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableList">
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_a</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_b</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_c</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_d</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_e</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableList">
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_a</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_b</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_c</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_d</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_e</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableList">
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_a</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_b</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_c</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_d</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_e</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableList">
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_a</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_b</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_c</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_d</td>
<td class="tableList-TD-first">content_e</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help. What about situation when table is more way wider than the screen? Will Header scroll on sides with table?

Comment: don't forget to vote up if it works, this helps to verify answers for others in a similar situation. In this case for oversized tables I think again CSS issue. If the header table is css `position: fixed` then it won't scroll sideways. so instead try `position: absolute`.

Comment: I know where problem is. My main table (this without header) has no width, but i cant set width because table must expand to right because there can be more columns- its about good reading data. So table has only min-width for <td>. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: haha, so reluctant to vote up? okay well nevermind, code snippet above revised with all the magic you seek. specify the minimum widths as described at the bottom of the css. note also that I've added a scrollLeft variable and `$('.stickymenu').css({ left: -scrollLeft + 8 });` to the js activate sideways scrolling on the `.stickymenu` class. same snippet here: https://jsfiddle.net/manoeuvres/3d387wtr/

Comment: hmm... It works after add <div>. I don't know why but it works only with <div>:) Thanks for help mate.